# What are the ways to analyze a csv file in GCP Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Working on a company that moved to GCP workspace.

I am a Novice in gcp.
Scenario : I have a file (csv) in a google bucket.
Earlier we used to have these files within our linux dev boxes, Where I could run a lot of linux commands to analyze and get details.
Details like : Getting the Max value within a column, Average, Unique values, extract a line matching a string, checking if a value is present in a column and much more.

What are the options I have for a similar file within gcp bucket?
Bringing this file into a linux compute instance is not a good option as we now have limited space in these machines and is shared by a lot of devs. Persistent disks not allowed.

Any other options where I can "analyze" the csv file and extract the information I am looking for?

Better? maybe even show this as a dashboard?

I have seen videos of Google App Scripts where one can create good interfaces. I believe this only works with gsuite applications. Am I correct?

Any suggestions for a novice?

PS : I even tried to create a jenkins job, (again a novice here) but a simple command as

`sh "gsutil -m cat ${params.InputPathHardCoded}/* > gs://MyFolder/NewFile.csv"`
is throwing errors.

Any better / faster options ?

Comment: The shell does not know about the scheme `gs://`. `gsutil` can read from stdin. Replace `> gs://MyFolder/NewFile.csv` with `| gsutil cp - gs://MyFolder/NewFile.csv`

Comment: Try Cloud Dataprep. It can provide you some metrics. Another solution is to load the data in BigQuery (external table or native table) and to query it with BigQuery (SQL). Last option, is to use Looker Studio and create dashboard on top of the files.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Looker studio fits my requirements perfectly, but there is a catch. I would want users to select their respective csv files and once they click upload / Ok ..Then create the analysis on the uploaded csv. In other words, my report would be constant (min, max, average, graph of values, choice of columns and filter by row) but the source file would change.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you for the tip. shall try this out.